# How can I delete files remotely using curl on http server?

Tags: bash, http, curl, delete-file

I am trying to get specific files on http://example.com/ and then delete them by sending a delete request using curl.

I know how to send a delete request for a single file, but what I want is to delete all the files older then one day using curl on http server.

Comment: I need use curl since the entire script is curl. This is just a part of my task. My entire task in bash and curl

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use curl...

> **I know how to send a delete request for a single file, but what I want is to delete all the files older then one day using curl on http
>   server.**

R: if all the files you want to delete is the resource "http://example.com/20160904", you just pass that url do your curl command. Now, if you have files inside "http://example.com/myfiles" but not all files need to be deleted, then you won't be able to delete them in one shot. You'll have to write a script to check first for files (resources) to be deleted and then use the curl command to delete each one of them.

1) Check file name or file metadata looking for date
    created/modified;

2) If that file was created or modified on "today - 1 day" then;

3) Fire the curl command do delete that resource.

Comment: Ok my problem is in the script part, I don't understand how to get the files that are older then a day ? How can I write the script in the way that will catch all files older then one day and keep them until curl fires ?

Comment: You should create a new question and ask that same exact question. Add more details like, I need to run the script on a Linux box or Windows Server. If you have a programming language in mind, tell that you want to use that programming language.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP stands for Hyper Text **Transfer** Protocol. Even if you issue a DELETE request, it is completely up to the server (and if the server acts as Gateway the application behind) to really **do** something with the object (URL) you are trying to affect.

So the simple answer here is that you may try to access the file using another method, such as ssh, rsync, or something else.